# Link text of multiple tag question feed is going out of range

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, feed, search

I am using the following URL to get all questions tagged `*sql*` or `vb6`. (`*` is used as wildcard to get questions of all tags contains `sql`).
[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*sql*+or+vb6`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*sql*+or+vb6)

I found the text of tag question feed is going out of range:

[image]

When we hover on that link it shows whole sentence in tool-tip (as shown in image).
So if it is not a bug then it is a feature-request to reduce text to fit in screen (set max length) something like this:

`newest mysql or sql or sql-server or ... or vb6 questions feed`

Comment: The [meta-tag:feed] tag is for RSS feed, it's not relevant here that's why I removed it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Isn't this question about RSS feed?

Comment: No, this is about search and search results. RSS for example is the "question feed" links e.g. [feed for this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/147699) (you'll need RSS feed reader to properly view it)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I am also taking about RSS feed. See this http://i.stack.imgur.com/2f1PK.png

Comment: Sorry, can't see any problem in the screenshot you posted.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Actually in this screenshot there is no problem. I show you to understand that I am talking about RSS feed. Just compare both screenshots (screenshot of question and in comment)

Comment: I see now, you talk about the link to the question feed - so far the tag was used to mention the RSS feed itself, the link is mere design.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd So using this feed tag okay or not? Look at this screenshot to be more clear. http://i.stack.imgur.com/2EBPJ.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in the next build, we'll change those links to end in `or (x more)` after the tag list gets too long (currently longer than 3 tags).